# S3 presigned URL, using IAM users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

There is a requirement to generate pre-signed URL's for accessing private S3 objects with configurable access time ranging from 1-6 days. Using a role (on EC2), I was able to generate URL and then access it for fairly long time before it fails with "Invalid Token" (the url though has an expiration that is valid).

With some checks found that its cause , the role's access id, secret keys are rotated at max 12 hrs, the other option is using an IAM USER whos keys do not expire.

I did try the same but with little luck.

```
    session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=getkval(KEY_ID), aws_secret_access_key=getkval(A_KEY),region_name='ap-south-1')
    s3Client = session.client('s3', config= boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
    url=s3Client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket': filebucket, 'Key': key}, ExpiresIn = 86400*int(days))
```

This generates a presigned url with Access key associated with user (can see it in link), however it expires sooner than the expiry. What could be wrong ?

Comment: sigv4 pre-signed URLs have an expiration range of 1 second up to 7 days. What are you requesting and when does it actually expire?

Comment: ...and what message do you see when it expires, and how do the timestamps in the message compare to the values in the signed URL for `X-Amz-Date` and `X-Amz-Expires`?

Comment: And what have you defined as `days`? (In `ExpiresIn = 86400*int(days)`)

Comment: days is a configurable parameter int, typically 1 to 6

Comment: When I click on the link , I get "invalid token". In the url itself I can see expiry date is set correctly as per expiry parameter set. (with days as int 1). Below is one of the pre-signed url that was generated. 

https://bucketsamples3.s3.amazonaws.com/5a3a0c1f-f9bd-4d74-bfaa-c55d1aa9d11e/xxxxxxxxxxx.pdf
?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
&X-Amz-Expires=86400
&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%2F20180521%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
&X-Amz-Date=20180521T134015Z
&X-Amz-Signature=667d43fd7d5b9e87014c2c1b4ddd23a91b11925f036733cc61d61fa7cf4cf783

Comment: Reason why I am using a IAM user credential instead of a role.  [AWS FORUM](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=153786)